# Design SQL Schema for User Interests

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to find the best approach for designing sql schema for the following scenario: 
-A User can have multiple interests 
-The platform provides predefined interests from which the user can select from 
-The User can create his own custom interests and select them

I'm suggesting the following schema:

**interests**(id, name) 
**custom_interests** (id, name, user_id) 
**user_interests** (id, interest_id, custom_interest_id, user_id) 
 // Where (interest_id is NULL and custom_interest_id IS NOT NULL) OR (interest_id is NOT NULL AND custom_interest_id IS NULL)

in this approach users in **user_interests** table , user would be able to select from **custom_interests** items that dont belong to him.

it sure can be restricted with proper backend validation, but does anyone has a better suggestion for this type of scenario ?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Would standard and custom interests always have the same basic structure (ID, NAME) or would/could their design diverge in the future? When you are looking at the interests a user has, do you want to treat them all as a single entity or would you want to treat standard and custom interests as separate entities?

Comment: @NickW standard and custom interests have the same structure (id, name), and i would want to treat them as a single entity (frontend will be responsible to differentiate platform provided and custom interests by color)

Comment: You say: *i would want to treat them as a single entity* then do so. **Get rid of custom_interests**. After all the only difference seems to be `interests` are those things the dev/admin team thought of and pre-populates and `custom_interests` are those that dev/admin did not think of. Consider what does the system do when a 2nd user adds the same interest? What about the 10th or 100th user adding the same?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you separate system-provided interests and user-custom interests. Because what if different users choose the same name for their custom interests? You don't want to only store one row of user-custom interest in the table. Who knows what they might want to do in the future, like update the name or delete the custom interest they created? Even if you perceive them as the same structure, they are actually different entities representing different things in the system (by displaying them in different colors, you are actually acknowledging that there are differences).

The table design I would suggest:

```
system_interests: id, name
custom_interests: id, name
user_system_interests: user_id, system_interest_id (user can have multiple interests)
user_custom_interests: user_id, custom_interest_id
```

This design opens up a more flexible approach for your system. Because someday you might find that the structure of `custom_interests` is not actually the same as `system_interests` (or vice versa), so you can easily modify them separately.